# Select all neighbor polygons algorithm

Tags: gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl, turfjs

I am trying to select all neighboring polygons in mapbox gl using turf.js and I am using

```
turf.intersect(poly[0], item);
```

And sometimes it is fine, but it looks like the input polygons data is bad, and it looks like there is some gaps between neigbour polygons coordinates(the neighbour points lat/lon doesn not match, or multipolygons), so is there any other algorithm to get the neighbour polygons? [image]

Answer (score 2):

This is working as it should. The reason it is not selecting the polygon above is because it is **not** a neighbor (due to bad geometry etc.).

A way to work around this bad geometry would be to [buffer](http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) the polygon by a small amount and then do an intersect using the slightly larger buffered layer that will span the gaps between your existing polygons.